# Getting "Method not found: 'Boolean Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions.IsValid" in VS2019

Tags: json

I've copied a sample from the site https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
...
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name': {'type': 'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type': 'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
// true
```

When I try to debug it in VS2019 I get an exception: "Method not found: 'Boolean Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions.IsValid"

I feel so stupid for asking, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could be version issue. make sure you have the correct version of newtonsoft installed in all the involved projects

Comment: I just created an new project and downloaded the Newtonsoft packages - still the same error.

Comment: we will need a reproducible example

Comment: I tried running the above on a connect virtual machine with VS 2017 and it worked.  Something must be wrong with my laptop.  I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I removed (actually renamed) entries in my GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSILl) where I had entries to three NewtonSoft libraries.  And now the above code works.  I think these GAC entries were made by Xsd2Code.

Comment: Yes I suspected as much.... When you get "Method not found" it usually means a version conflict. And you should use newtonsoft from a nuget package.

Comment: I was using Newtonsoft from a nuget package but Xsd2Code had installed an older version in the GAC.  My project was using Xsd2Code and I believe that it loads the DLLs from the GAC and those are the ones that get called when I tried to debug my code - and that is why I got "method not found".   Thanks for your help.